# How to update version of Microsoft.NETCore.App SDK in VS 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, coreclr

I have ASP.NET Core API project which was initially developed using  VS 2015. I installed VS 2017 and let it convert the project.
Then i goto Project Properties -> Application ->Target framework and change the target framework to .NETCoreApp 1.1.

as soon as i do that i get 2 errors

> Error     One or more projects are incompatible with
> .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
>
> Error     Project Api is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Project Api supports: netcoreapp1.1
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)

when i checked  `Dependencies -> SDK -> Microsoft.NETCore.App -> Properties` it shows version `1.0.4` and `SDK Root` to `C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\microsoft.netcore.app\1.0.4`

I have already installed `Microsoft.NETCore.App` SDK version `1.1.2` on my machine.

When i goto Nuget Package Manager to update SDK version, it shows its `Autoreferenced` and update button is disabled.

How do i update project's SDK's version to `1.1.2`?

Also why VS studio reference SDK from `C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\microsoft.netcore.app` instead of from `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.1.2`

**Update 1**

Actually `1.1.2` is not SDK version. [As of 7/20/2017](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core) the latest SDK version is `1.0.4` and Runtime version is `1.1.2` On my machine I have `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4` SDK and `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.1.2` runtime installed.

So as i mentioned erlier, when i open converted project in VS 2017, I see Dependencies -> SDK ->Microsoft.NETCore.App - Properties version is `1.0.4` and SDK Root is `C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\microsoft.netcore.app\1.0.4`

Now I added new project in the same solution, however new project's Dependencies -> SDK ->Microsoft.NETCore.App -> Properties version is 1.1.2 and SDK root `C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\microsoft.netcore.app\1.1.2`

I am not sure which is  correct here, the SDK version of the converted project or SDK version of the newly added project?

Infact if create a brand new project in VS 2017 i see its Dependencies -> SDK ->Microsoft.NETCore.App -> Properties version is 1.1.2

`1.1.2` SDK not even SDK available. Why VS 2017 shows runtime version as SDK version

is this a bug in VS 2017?

Answer (score 3):

Right click your project and edit your `csproj` file.

If you see a line like this:

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

Then update it to `1.1.2` or just remove this line. Then restore the packages (maybe using command line `dotnet restore`, I don't know whether VS will do this automatically).

This way you can update `Microsoft.NETCore.App` to `1.1.2` and this should fix your problem.

Comment: @LP13 I think the version of `Microsoft.NETCore.App` is actually the runtime version. As you can see, if you change the `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` in csproj file, the version of `Microsoft.NETCore.App` will change accordingly. So I think `1.1.2` is correct for you. `1.0.4` is not only the version of the newest SDK, but also another runtime version for 
.NET Core 1.0, you can see it at https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md

Comment: Yes you are correct that there is also a runtime version `1.0.4`. and it is installed on my machine.  Its very confusing that in VS it is listed under SDK. They should rename that folder under Dependencies as `runtime` or something else

Answer (score 0):

I`d suggest you to update every of your project dependencies at least to version 1.1.0, then try to change the version once again. Make sure to clean and rebuild your solution after all.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a project using .NET Core 3.1 and I wanted to update to 5.0, which is the latest version at the moment. In the csproj file, I deleted the line preceded by the minus symbol and added the line preceded by the plus symbol, as shown below [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
- <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
+    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Then, I created a file called ***global.json*** whose content was the following:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "5.0.103"
  }
}
```

For this, I used the command: `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 5.0.103` [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x)

Finally, I compiled and run the application and worked!